# How can I recreate this Material and flat Colors?

Tags: materials

I really like the flat colors under the Materials viewport in Cycles render

How can I recreate this for use in a game engine?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

It can be easily done by simply linking color node straight to output, bypassing any kind of shaders

[image]

But I don't know how it'll export for a game, you can always use Emission shader on strength 1, which doesn't modify visual appearance at all